# blanked the day commemorating victims of state terror -- what really does "blanked" mean there?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Russia opens major gulag museum as Putin blanks victims' commemorations](http://news.yahoo.com/russia-opens-major-gulag-museum-putin-blanks-victims-194916064.html)

Example:

> Russia on Friday opened a major new museum on the horrors of the Soviet gulag labour camp system but President Vladimir Putin **blanked** the day commemorating victims of state terror.

What exactly do you think they mean by the verb *blanked* in that passage? The most common usage, and drawing on my personal experience with the English language I assume the only one out there that's actually in common use (in North American English at least), is to blank something out which basically means to make something a clean slate again, but that doesn't really fit the semantics of the sentence.

Comment: typo for "blocked" aka he refused to approve a day of commemoration?

Comment: Slightly strange word choice imo but I think it means "ignored" in the sense of "not acknowledge".

Comment: A native English speaker would never use blanked in that manner. It is an odd sentence from a non-native speaker, or a bad translation. I agree with JMB that it means "ignored."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **blank** someone is to completely ignore them.

> The girl he liked completely blanked him.

Like a blank stare, not looking at anything.